# Getting a name error NameError, function is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, nameerror

> File "/Users//Desktop/A5/driverModule.py", line 22, in controller
>       tripInfo()
>   **NameError: name 'tripInfo' is not defined**

Okay I'm really stuck and can't figure out why I'm getting this error. Any help is appreciated.

Driver Module

```
from TripInfoModule import *


def controller():
totalDrivingTime = 0
totalFuelCost = 0
totalAmountEarned = 0
totalNetIncome = 0
totalDistance = 0
totalFuelComsumed = 0
totalBreakTime = 0

input("Welcome to the updated trip income calculator. Press enter to continue: ")
i = "y"
while i == "y":
    getDistance()
    getEarningpPerMile()
    getDrivingTime()
    getBreakTime()
    getFuelConsumed()
    getCostperGallon()
    tripInfo()

    i = input("Would you like to add a new trip? Enter y to add a new trip, "
          "or enter n to exit.")
print("Total fuel cost: $", format(totalFuelCost, '.2f'))
print("Total amount of fuel consumed:", format(totalFuelComsumed, '.2f'), "gallons")
print("Total miles driven:", format(totalDistance, '.2f'), "miles")
print("Total driving time:", format(totalDrivingTime, '.2f'), "hours")
print("Total break time:", format(totalBreakTime, '.2f'), "hours")
print("Total earned: $", format(totalAmountEarned, '.2f',))
print("Total net income: $", format(totalNetIncome, '.2f'))


def main():
controller()


main()
```

Module 2

```
from userInputModule import *

import driverModule

def tripInfo():
getNetIncome()
getTotalFuelConsumed()
getAmountEarned()
getNetIncome()
getTotalBreakTime()
getTotalDistance()
getTotalFuelConsumed()
getTotalDrivingTime()

def getFuelCost():
fuelConsumed = getFuelConsumed()
costPerGallon = getCostperGallon()
totalFuelCost = driverModule.controller()

gasUsed = float(fuelConsumed)
costPerGal = float(costPerGallon)

fuelCost = gasUsed * costPerGal
totalFuelCost += fuelCost

print("Your total fuel cost is:", format(fuelCost, '.2f'))

return fuelCost, totalFuelCost


def getAmountEarned():
distance = getDistance()
earnings = getEarningpPerMile()
totalAmountEarned = driverModule.controller()

distanceVar = float(distance)
earningsVar = float(earnings)

amountEarned = distanceVar * earningsVar
totalAmountEarned += amountEarned

print("Your earnings are:", format(amountEarned, '.2f'))

return amountEarned, totalAmountEarned


def getNetIncome():
totalNetIncome = driverModule.controller()
fuelConsumed = getFuelConsumed()
costPerGallon = getCostperGallon()
distance = getDistance()
earnings = getEarningpPerMile()

gasUsed = float(fuelConsumed)
costPerGal = float(costPerGallon)

distanceVar = float(distance)
earningsVar = float(earnings)

earnedIncome = distanceVar * earningsVar

fuelCost = gasUsed * costPerGal
taxAmount = earnedIncome * .08
netIncome = (earnedIncome - taxAmount) - fuelCost

totalNetIncome += netIncome

print("Your net income is:", format(netIncome, '.2f'))

return netIncome


def getTotalBreakTime():
breakTime = getBreakTime()
totalBreakTime = driverModule.controller()

breakTimeVar = float(breakTime)
totalBreakTime += breakTimeVar

return totalBreakTime


def getTotalDistance():
distance = getDistance()
totalDistance = driverModule.controller()

distanceVar = float(distance)
totalDistance += distanceVar

return totalDistance


def getTotalFuelConsumed():
fuelConsumed = getFuelConsumed()
totalFuelConsumed = driverModule.controller()

fuelConsumedVar = float(fuelConsumed)
totalFuelConsumed += fuelConsumedVar

return totalFuelConsumed


def getTotalDrivingTime():
drivingTime = getDrivingTime()
totalDrivingTime = driverModule.controller()

drivingTimeVar = float(drivingTime)
totalDrivingTime += drivingTimeVar

return totalDrivingTime
```

Module 1

```
def getDistance():
distance = input("Please enter the number of miles driven: ")
distanceStr = distance.replace(".", "")

while not distanceStr.isnumeric():
    distance = input("Please enter a numeric distance "
                           "only that is non-zero: ")
    distanceStr = distance.replace(".", "")

return distance


def getEarningpPerMile():
earningsPerMile = input("Please enter the amount earned per mile: ")
earningsPerMileStr = earningsPerMile.replace(".", "")

while not earningsPerMileStr.isnumeric():
    earningsPerMile = input("Please enter a numeric number "
                           "only that is non-zero: ")
    earningsPerMileStr = earningsPerMile.replace(".", "")

return earningsPerMile


def getDrivingTime():
totalDrivingTime = input("Please enter total driving time: ")
totalDrivingTimeStr = totalDrivingTime.replace(".", "")

while not totalDrivingTimeStr.isnumeric():
    totalDrivingTime = input("Please enter a numeric number "
                           "only that is non-zero: ")
    totalDrivingTimeStr = totalDrivingTime.replace(".", "")

return totalDrivingTime


def getBreakTime():
breakTime = input("Please enter the amount of break time taken: ")
breakTimeStr = breakTime.replace(".", "")

while not breakTimeStr.isnumeric():
    breakTime = input("Please enter a numeric number "
                           "only that is non-zero: ")
    breakTimeStr = breakTime.replace(".", "")

return breakTime


def getFuelConsumed():
fuelConsumed = input("Please enter the ammount of fuel consumed: ")
fuelConsumedStr = fuelConsumed.replace(".", "")

while not fuelConsumedStr.isnumeric():
    fuelConsumed = input("Please enter a numeric number "
                           "only that is non-zero: ")
    fuelConsumedStr = fuelConsumed.replace(".", "")

return fuelConsumed

def getCostperGallon():
costPerGallon = input("Please enter cost per gallon: ")
costPerGallonStr = costPerGallon.replace(".", "")

while not costPerGallonStr.isnumeric():
    costPerGallon = input("Please enter a numeric number "
                           "only that is non-zero: ")
    costPerGallonStr = costPerGallon.replace(".", "")

return costPerGallon
```

Comment: have you `import module2` inside driver module?

Comment: Yes. That's what I don't understand. I imported it correctly but it still is giving a name error

Comment: try this `print(name_of_the_file_.tripInfo())` what it return?

Comment: what is the name of the file you are working??

Comment: I have 3 modules I designed. The first module gets the user input, the second module does some math and gets some totals. The last module is the driver that runs the whole program. I'm having an issue with the second module

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of the reasons that `*` imports are discouraged. Start by being explicit here

```
from TripInfoModule import tripInfo, ...
```

If that line can't find `tripInfo`, then you have got closer to the bug sooner.

Now `tripInfo` is defined in the thing you call "Module2"

This file of course needs to be named "TripInfoModule". Make sure there are no old versions or `.pyc` files that could be loaded instead of the one you are expecting

Comment: now I get this error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'tripInfo'

Comment: @WonderphuL, yes this tells you that Python isn't finding `tripInfo` in `TripInfoModule.py`, so that is what you need to fix

Comment: Okay thats what im confused by. Why is it not finding it?

Comment: Because it's not there. But you also know it's not a SyntaxError or some other problem. I can't tell you more without seeing the actual file. Double check that it's loading the file that you think it is.